# Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process ,Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Though I have called my  call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first in my MainActivity,

here is the repo 
https://github.com/THIYAGU22/DuesettlementDetails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha13'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer the crash stopped , but the details are not stored in firebase , while trying logcat it shows me to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) and so i did in my MainActivity , still the error persists in saving database

Comment: The fact that you have another issue, it means that the initial error disappeared and this are good news :) but this sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. As a personal guess, I think that you are using a wrong database reference but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.