# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process

Tags: java, android, firebase, illegalstateexception

I created a new project and added firebase via android studio tool of firebase. Did everything as instructed but I am getting this error during lunching the app.

```
Process: com.chitchat, PID: 20084
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chitchat/com.chitchat.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.chitchat. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2951)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.chitchat. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:219)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.chitchat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

MainActivity.java is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MainActivity.this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    //updateUI(currentUser);

    if(currentUser == null){
        Intent startAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Start_Activity.class);
        startActivity(startAct);
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

and gradle.build is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chitchat"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


}
```

Project-level gradle.build

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Couldn't find anything on web! Have added `firebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` which was not present in any instructions but still the same error on emulator and on device.

Comment: is it possible that i have misconfig firebase which is causing this error!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue too.I saw many people were having the issue in recent weeks.There is issue with

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

change it to

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763333/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized-in-this-process-make-sure-to-call-fireba)!

because AGP is having some issues according to this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54229857/android-default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized-in-this-process-error-with-agp-3)!
I think this will solve your issue.

EDIT: As of 30th jan 2021, just change to latest version of all firebase class dependencies and it should work: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'`

Comment: I had updated google-services to 4.3.9 and experienced the problem. Downgrading to 4.3.4 got around the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to bottom of your `build.gradle`:

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: Post your project-level `build.gradle`

Comment: @AjayChoudhary Try this: `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext())`

Comment: tried this FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext()) : no luck!

Comment: Updated project-level build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Add following code in your `Application` class instead of `Activity`, in order to initialize Firebase into entire application, not just one Activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
}
```

Also, you need to move your apply plugin code from **top** to **bottom**
Referencing: [Add Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk)

```
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It requires that the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line be at the **bottom** of your `app/build.gradle` file so that no dependency collisions are introduced. You can see the result of this step by running ./gradlew `:app:dependencies`. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

Also, try syncing all firebase and gms:google-services dependencies to the latest version.

Comment: I created a new java class, extends Application. Created entry in manifest file. Used your code in it. Still getting the same error!
Please let me know if i misunderstood anything!

Comment: For those using kotlin DSL see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55167302/2445763)

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to add com.google.gms:google-services:x.x.x at root level build.gradle.
Like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

then add google plugin at the **bottom** of your build.gradle(app).

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' is already present. I added 'apply plugin' but this didn't help. Same error!