# How to apply the Google Services Plugin in a Kotlin Buildscript

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

How can I apply the Google Services plugin to the bottom of my app module build.gradle.kts file?

Doing it using the `plugins {}` block at the top of the file gives a warning and using the same block below the file causes an error since this block can't be used twice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Applying the Google Services Plugin in a Kotlin build script is different from the way you would do it in Groovy.

```
// Add this at the bottom of your file to actually apply the plugin
apply(plugin = "com.google.gms.google-services")
```

The `apply` function applies a plugin or a script using the given options provided as a map.

Comment: a [cleaner way](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/app/build.gradle.kts#L102) of doing this

Comment: It says `Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.` . How can I make it be found? In gradle files, I had to add classpath. Where is it now?

Answer (score 0):

There is no longer need to add `Google Services Plugin` at the bottom of the new `.kts` files.

Just add it as a regular plugin.

If you DO NOT have `libs.versions.toml` file, then add in both gradle files:

module app:

```
id("com.google.gms.google-services")
```

module project-name:

```
id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
```

Or, if you DO have `libs.versions.toml` file, then add in this file:

in [versions] block:

```
google-services = "4.4.0"
```

in [plugins] block:

```
google-services = { id = "com.google.gms.google-services", version.ref = "google-services" }
```

and in gradle files:

gradle module app:

```
alias(libs.plugins.google.services)
```

gradle module project-name:

```
alias(libs.plugins.google.services) apply false
```