# App crashes abruptly at the line FirebaseAuth.getInstance() even though it is properly configured and dependencies etc are updated, how to fix this?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, build.gradle

I'm building an app that requires login sign up functionalities but it crashes right when the login activity is launched, in the crash logs it suggests the crash to have occured on
FirebaseAuth.getInstance() ; this line

I even tried doing this
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); but still the app crashes with same reason

This is what my logcat says:

```
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process    com.example.myjournal. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.**
                                                                                                        at   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:179)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:272)
                                                                                                        at com.example.myjournal.LoginScreen.onCreate(LoginScreen.java:47)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8130)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8110)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1343)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3781)
```

Here are some relevant gradle details

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    }

    android {
        namespace 'com.example.myjournal'
        compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myjournal"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
   }

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'


}
```

all the things are latest versions too

also another relevant gradle detail

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false

}
```

i tried to update all the dependencies and plugins to latest versions
updated the compileSDK and targetSDK to 34 as it was suggested by android studio on the first crash
properly enabled signup options in firebase authentication in the console
tried to use this initialisation method too FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324713/java-lang-illegalstateexception-default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized-in-this

Comment: "even though it is properly configured" clearly not.